# How to parse JSON into HighCharts line graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to parse the following JSON string remotely:

```
[{"name":"Object1","data":[1,2]},{"name":"Object2","data":[3,4]}]
```

I am doing so with the following code:

```
$(function () {
  var chart;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line',
        marginRight: 130,
        marginBottom: 25
      },
      title: {
        text: 'hits by time',
        x: -20 //center
      },
      subtitle: {
        text: 'Source:',
        x: -20
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['8am', '9am', '10am', '11am', '12pm', '1pm',
        '2pm', '3pm', '4pm', '5pm', '6pm', '7pm']
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Hits'
        },
        plotLines: [{
          value: 0,
          width: 1,
          color: '#808080'
        }]
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
          return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
          this.x +': '+ this.y;
        }
      },
      legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -10,
        y: 100,
        borderWidth: 0
      },
      series: []
    };  

    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/jsonget', function(data) {

      var series = {
        data: []
      };

      $.each(data, function(i,item){
        alert(item.name);
        series.name = item.name;
        $.each(item.data, function(j,dataitem){
          alert(dataitem);
          series.data.push(parseFloat(dataitem[i]));                  
        });
      });

      options.series.push(series);    

      // Create the chart
      var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
  });
});
```

The chart does not render, but does so when I substitute the remote portion for the CSV example on the site.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, would you mind showing how you create your json array? I'm trying to figure out how to get brackets around my data using php arrays. Naming the series etc I can do. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell your `data` seems to be well formed. So, this should do it:

```
var chart;
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8080/UDPver/tagdiscover', function(data) {
  // Populate series
  options.series = data;    
  // Create the chart
  chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: if i have 2 y axis? i.e. one x axis and two y axes!

Answer (score 2):

The problems is that the chart then is redrawn. So if you have other lines that is disabled (from legend), it will be visible agian when you do a update.
I have 5 lines in my graph. It is updated every second. 
From the legend I can disable/remove some of the lines from the graph.
But using this method above (it works) the complete graph is redrawn and all lines is visible again. 
Is it possible to just update the series (lines) and not the paramaters?

Like this (not working):

```
function doAjaxData() {
            AjaxLoadingIcon(1);
            $.ajax({
                url: getAjaxUrl(1),
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                success: function (json) {
                    AjaxLoadingIcon(0);
                    gchartOptions.series = [];
                    gchartOptions.series = json;
                    // gchart = new Highcharts.Chart(gchartOptions);
                    gchart.render();
                    _updateTimer = window.setTimeout("doAjaxData()", 1000);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Atma.
You just should write just `dataitem` instead of `dataitem[i]` and it will work.

```
  $.each(data, function(i,item){
    alert(item.name);
    series.name = item.name;
    $.each(item.data, function(j,dataitem){
      alert(dataitem);
      series.data.push(parseFloat(dataitem[i]));                  
    });
  });
```